# Routing traffic via proxy to a specific adapter?

Tags: linux, iptables

I am using squid proxy running on 127.0.0.1:3128, I am trying to route all traffic that is going through my proxy server, to use a specific network adapter.

Command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 3128 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.43.76:3128
```

I have tried the following with no luck, `192.168.43.76` being the local Ipv4 of the adapter.

`ip r show table all` displays:

```
default via 127.0.0.1 dev lo table 3 
default via 192.168.1.254 dev enp4s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp4s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.210 metric 100 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.76 metric 600 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.1.0 dev enp4s0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.210 
local 192.168.1.210 dev enp4s0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.1.210 
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev enp4s0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.210 
broadcast 192.168.43.0 dev wlp3s0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.76 
local 192.168.43.76 dev wlp3s0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.43.76 
broadcast 192.168.43.255 dev wlp3s0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.76 
2a00:23c7:3c05:7c01::/64 dev enp4s0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp4s0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
default via fe80::8e19:b5ff:fe44:5852 dev enp4s0 proto ra metric 20100 pref medium
local ::1 dev lo table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2a00:23c7:3c05:7c01:3763:cf65:958b:dfe9 dev enp4s0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2a00:23c7:3c05:7c01:d5e5:e0ff:34a5:d2b9 dev enp4s0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::54c1:a358:586:b470 dev wlp3s0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::ae7d:6464:5c50:e88f dev enp4s0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev enp4s0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev wlp3s0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

I'm trying to use `default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600` as the adapter, which is using WiFi, while allowing everything else outside the proxy to still use ethernet / default adapter.

Comment: What do you have in your routing table? `ip r show table all` and what is the gateway for the nic that you do want to use?

Comment: HI @NiKiZe I have updated my question, thanks.

Comment: Route exists with high metric, you are telling any local traffic to enter the proxy. My mistake for not noticing earlier, but what config do you have in presumably squid to try and use that interface.

You will probably also need a multihomed config. using `ip rule` to have a separate table for outgoing traffic with `192.168.43.76` as the source.